# Is the phrase "tirade of" grammatically correct

Tags: grammaticality

This question has to do with the phrase "tirade of". Can you say the following: "She commenced a tirade of yelling and screaming at her husband?" Or would it be more correct to say: "She commenced a tirade, yelling and screaming at her husband"

Answer (score 2):

Both are totally fine. If you check the [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/tirade), they have a sample sentence using a 'tirade of abuse', so the first one is definitely ok. It can also be used without the prepositional phrase, so the second answer is also perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the construction *tirade of* is more appropriate and commmon with a noun than with a gerund.

- She yelled/screamed a tirade of abuse
- it was time for her to release a tirade of insults... <sup>[World Dictionary of Foreign Expressions: A Resource for Readers and Writers](http://books.google.it/books?id=a4ddQNrt8e8C&pg=PA383&dq=%22tirade%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=m8hhVMX6NqOS7Aa8poCICA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22tirade%20of%22&f=false)</sup>
- [He learnt to bear the] tirade of *criticisms* over the years. <sup>[Your Dictionary](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/tirade)</sup>
- A tirade of *invective* is unlikely to get printed.
- She launched into a tirade of abuse against politicians.   <sup>[Oxford Learners Dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/tirade)</sup>
- a tirade of false statements/allegations/complaints/accusations/ etc.

On Google there are 75 examples of [tirade of yelling](https://www.google.com/search?q=tirade&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&oq=tirade&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3826j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22tirade%20of%20yelling%22&start=70) and 78 of [tirade of screaming](https://www.google.com/search?q=tirade&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&oq=tirade&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3826j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22tirade%20of%20screaming%22&start=90), whereas [tirade of insults](https://www.google.com/search?q=tirade&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&oq=tirade&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3826j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22tirade%20of%20insults%22&start=140) fetches 99,100 results and [tirade of abuse](https://www.google.com/search?q=tirade&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&oq=tirade&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3826j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22tirade%20of%20abuse%22&start=200) has 1,760,000 results.